# Why is there no __doPostBack() JavaScript added to a CommandField's Update button in GridView when rendered to HTML

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, commandfield

I have a basic `GridView` with a `CommandField` which uses the CommandField's in-built Edit, Cancel, Update and Delete buttons, with the `ButtonType` property set to "Image" (ImageButtons), defined as:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
OnRowEditing="gv_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="gv_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="gv_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="gv_RowDeleting">
<Columns>
    <asp:CommandField 
        ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" ButtonType="Image"
        EditImageUrl="~\Images\Icons\gridView_Edit.png"
        CancelImageUrl="~\Images\Icons\gridView_CancelEdit.png"
        UpdateImageUrl="~\Images\Icons\gridView_Update.png"/>
</Columns>
```

The server-side C# event handlers for the OnRowEditing, OnRowCancelingEdit, OnRowUpdating and OnRowDeleting events are working fine and are defined as:

```
protected void gv_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) { }
protected void gv_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e) { }
protected void gv_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e) { }
protected void gv_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e) { }
```

When the page is rendered to HTML, the `ImageButtons` in the `CommandField` are rendered to the following (simplified) `<input>` tags:

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$Body$gv$ctl02$ctl00" src="Images/update.png" alt="Update" style="border-width:0px;">
<input type="image" src="Images/delete.png" alt="Delete" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Body$gv','Delete$0')" style="border-width:0px;">
<input type="image" src="Images/edit.png" alt="Edit" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Body$gv','Edit$0')" style="border-width:0px;">
<input type="image" src="Images/cancel.png" alt="Cancel" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$Body$gv','Cancel$0')" style="border-width:0px;">
```

*NOTE: In reality, only either Edit/Delete or Update/Cancel are rendered at any one time, depending on whether the GridView is in edit mode or not.*

So, why does the rendered Update button not use ASP.NET's __doPostBack JavaScript function, when the Delete, Edit and Cancel buttons do?

How is it that the `OnRowUpdating` event *is* handled?

**NOTE**: When using the default `ButtonType` for the `CommandField` it *does* render __doPostBack, but when using `ButtonType="Image"` __doPostBack is **not** included.

Answer (score 0):

Note that these 4 buttons are never displayed together, you have either "Edit" "Delete" or, after you click "Edit", you get "Update" "Cancel".

So just as you click your "Edit" button and the set of buttons changes from "Edit" "Delete" to "Update" "Cancel", your "Update" button WILL have the `__doPostback` attached to it.

The `OnRowUpdating` is then handled normally, by the `doPostback` just after you click the "Edit" button.

You can download one of my examples

http://www.ii.uni.wroc.pl/~wzychla/ra2829/example3a.zip

to see that. Just change the button type to `Image` in `Default.aspx` and attach your handlers to the grid.

Comment: I'm aware that all four buttons aren't rendered at once, I simplified my example for clarity. Still, at no point does the Update button have __doPostBack attached to it.

Comment: Did you download my concise example? Something else has to be in your code, because if you take a look at my example you will see that Update HAS the __doPostback on it.

Comment: Interestingly it does show __doPostBack with the default CommandField ButtonType, but my example shows ButtonType="Image", and that doesn't render __doPostBack for the Update ImageButton

Comment: In my example, the `__doPostBack` is present no matter which button type you set.